# Manage nuget packages with PackageReferences when .Net Framework+Standard+Core combined

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, .net-standard, packagereference

**Question:**

How to manage nuget packages in a `VisualStudio2017` solution with 3 platforms:

- *.Net Standard 1.3*
- *.Net Framework 4.6*
- *.Net Core 1.0*

**?**

I like the `PackageReference` approach, but i don't know how to use it. They talk about:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- ... -->
    <PackageReference Include="Contoso.Utility.UsefulStuff" Version="3.6.0" />
    <!-- ... -->
</ItemGroup>
```

- Does it mean that in general i need at least 3 *PackageReferences* for each of Framework/Standard/Core?
- How to manage the versions when we are stuck with `.Net Framework 4.6`?
- I also ran across the issue when i could not run a console `.net core` app referencing `.net standard` lib due to *nuget* versions compatibility problem.

In addition, i'd like to mention that i came across a couple of articles that stated that `.csproj`s are back and there's no need of `.xproj`, `project.json`. Personally, i like this idea to deal with `.csproj`s like previously.

---

**Context:**

I'm not a native English speaker and i'm very new to non-trivial nuget usages and `.Net` `Core`/`Standard` development.

I'm preparing to port a `.Net Framework` application to `.Net` `Framework`+`Standard`+`Core`.
This is now just a *WPF* application. But in the future it's intended to stay the same *WPF* app, but also to have a new `.Net Core` branch, raising from the existing logic.
I don't know exactly what the plans are for the possible new `.Net Core` branch. Most probably, the plans are to create an `ASP.Net Core` website. 
What i know for sure is that the task is to keep logic running as `.Net Framework` (with *WPF* UI) and also get it implemented as `.Net Core`.

I decided to use the combination of `Framework`+`Standard`+`Core` as the solution because of its simplicity. I mean that the conception is easy to understand: base classes (*standard*) used by 2 brances (*FWK*, *Core*). 
No need of mutitargeting or directives in code (conditional compilation). 
Implying that the new solution should be created from scratch by copy-pasting and modifying.
Still not 100% sure about the reasonability of this decision.

But the question implies that this very approach is to be taken: `Framework`+`Standard`+`Core`.

---

I hope taht this question is reasonable; i mean that the effective managing of nuget packages in such case is a good start for a successfull cross-platform project. Thanks!

Comment: When you are stuck on .NET Framework 4.6, do create a multi-targeting core library for `net46` and `netstandard20`. It is meaningless to target `netstandard13` as the API there is very limited, and you don't need to support legacy platforms like WP or Silverlight. Do your experiments with `PackageReference` and you don't even need to ask first questions. What exactly is the issue of "I also ran across the issue when i could not run a console .net core app referencing .net standard lib due to nuget versions compatibility problem"?

Comment: @LexLi it isn't "meaningless" - it just isn't typically useful unless you're actively trying to target some downlevel frameworks such as windows phone

Comment: @LexLi, thanx a lot! probably it's a good idea to do multitargeting. As for versions compatibility problem: i could not run a netcore1.0 console app referencing netstandard1.3 lib in vs17 (see next comment). Thanks!

Comment: @LexLi, Output:  The program '[12780] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450751 (0x80008081).
The program '[1996] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: I'm assuming that you're using the new SDK csproj format here, and something like:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.3;net46;netcoreap1.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

If the thing that you're referencing *exists and targets* all the same platforms as your project, it should *just work*. However, unless you're actually doing *something different* in Framework vs Standard vs Core, you might as well just target Standard, and in reality: many libs are now rebasing against `netstandard2.0` as the minimum. This may or may not be possible for you.

Versions don't work any differently on 4.6, unless there are problems with specific packages, but: you can get around that by using `Condition` attributes on the `<ItemGroup>` or on specific `<PackageReference>` elements. For example, I have a library that targets `net461` and `netstandard2.0`; and as it happens, everything I'm using *is already built into net461*, so to avoid having any downstream dependencies, I can do:

```
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net461'">
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'!='net461'">
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.Common" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection.Emit" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Permissions" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

This gives me (in nuget):

[image]

however; I could have left everything as just:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.Common" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection.Emit" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Permissions" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

and it would have worked fine - just : the `net461` target would list dependencies. I could also have listed completely different dependencies per target framework.